# How to do multiprocessing with class instances

Tags: python, class, wmi, instance, pickle

The program is designed to set up a process creation listener on various ips on the network.  The code is:

```
import multiprocessing
from wmi import WMI

dynaIP = ['192.168.165.1','192.168.165.2','192.168.165.3','192.168.165.4',]

class WindowsMachine:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip

        self.connection = WMI(self.ip)
        self.created_process = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.monitor_created_process, args = (self.connection,))
        self.created_process.start()

    def monitor_created_process(self, remote_pc):
        while True:
            created_process = remote_pc.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
            print('Creation:',created_process.Caption, created_process.ProcessId, created_process.CreationDate)
            return created_process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for ip in dynaIP:
        print('Running', ip)

        WindowsMachine(ip)
```

When running the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:/rmarshall/Work For Staff/ROB/_Python/__Python Projects Code/multipro_instance_stack_question.py", line 26, in <module>
    WindowsMachine(ip)
  File "U:/rmarshall/Work For Staff/ROB/_Python/__Python Projects Code/multipro_instance_stack_question.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.created_process.start()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 111, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 248, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 166, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'PyIID'>: attribute lookup builtins.PyIID failed
```

I have looked at other questions surrounding this issue but none I feel have clearly explained the work-around for pickling class instances.

Is anyone able to demonstrate this?

Comment: Probably not _the_ problem, but you need to declare `monitor_created_process(remote_pc)` as an instance method, i.e.`monitor_created_process(self, remote_pc)`.

Comment: Slightly confused by your `while` loop, that code can only ever run once, because you always return at the end of the loop.  What's the intention there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that multiprocessing [pickles](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) the arguments to the process in order to pass them around.  The `WMI` class is *not* pickleable, so cannot be passed as an argument to `multiprocessing.Process`.

If you want this to work, you can either:

- switch to using threads instead of processes (see the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) module)
- create the `WMI` object in `monitor_created_process`

I'd recommend the former, because there doesn't seem to be much use in creating full-blown processes.